# Query Not Executing Properly

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, jtable

I am making a Java GUI and on my GUI I have a JTable which is populated directly from database queries. What I am having issues with is adding a date range option to my GUI.

I have 2 JTextFields (startDate & endDate) which the user can type a specified range of dates (Format: DD-MMM-YY) and then the database queries and selected only those files in between the startDate and endDate.

Here is a the section of my code that is supposed to achieve the above.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            String start = startDate.getText();
            String end = endDate.getText();
                try {
                    String query1 = "SELECT * FROM FILES WHERE USER_ID = 1 AND FILE_DATE BETWEEN" + "'" + start + "'" + "AND" + "'" + end + "';";
                    pat = conn.prepareStatement(query1);
                    rs = pat.executeQuery();
                    tableData.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
}
```

I keep getting error:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

However I cannot seem to find what is wrong. The problem appears to be my query String however it appears to me that it is ended properly.

Here is the entire stacktrace:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:208)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:886)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1175)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1296)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3613)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3657)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1495)
at ManagementGUI$6.actionPerformed(ManagementGUI.java:481)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Check your FILE_DATE column in the database and see what the type and format is. For example, the default for a DATE datatype in Oracle is YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: The date column in my DB is Date. I am using Oracle DB as well. However all of my dates are in the format of: DD-MMM-YY.

Answer (score 0):

1) I suspect it is because there is no space when you are appending values. Give space after BETWEEN. Space before AND and after AND.

```
String query1 = "....... FILE_DATE BETWEEN " + "'" + start + "'" + " AND " + "'" + end + "';"
```

2) Move away from plain SQL and start using [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Comment: Fixed spacing errors, however I am still presented with the same error.

Comment: @qorz: Did you spend even a minute to understand what you did? Did you read the link and examples on how to use PreparedStatment? If yes, you could have observed that, parameters in query should be replaced with ? mark and you need to set values using set.... method to preparedstatement.

Comment: Yeah I understand parameters in a query are represented by a ?. Check below at Luigi's answer. It now gives me a different error.

Answer (score 0):

That is the space issue, you forgot to add some space after keywords. Try this one..

```
 String query1 = "SELECT * FROM FILES WHERE USER_ID = 1 AND FILE_DATE 
 BETWEEN " + "'" + start + "'" + " AND " + "'" + end + "';";
```

You must not pass them like this since they are the loop holes and your code would be vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: After correcting spacing issues I am still being given the same error. `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`

Comment: Yes, it did not work. Gave me same results as all the others.

Comment: try this
SELECT * FROM FILES WHERE USER_ID = 1 AND FILE_DATE 
 > " + "'" + start + "'" + " AND FILE_DATE < " + "'" + end + "';" and let me know if it works or not.

Comment: @qorz and print start and end date before executing the query. .i want to see the values as well

Comment: When I print out the values I get: `start: 01-FEB-15 end: 28-FEB-15 `produced same error: `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`

Comment: that won't work..change the date using date formatter class and convert the date into compatible sql date type. I hope start and end are not string variable they are of type DATE right?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `PreparedStatement` in the right way. Don't concatenate the parameters values in the query string, rather add it as parameter:

```
//use ? to refer to parameters in the PreparedStatement
String query1 = "SELECT * FROM FILES WHERE USER_ID = 1 AND FILE_DATE BETWEEN ? AND ?";
pat = conn.prepareStatement(query1);
//create a SimpleDateFormat instance that will parse each String
//and convert them into java.util.Date instances
//use the proper format to parse your dates
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("...");
//add the arguments to the PreparedStatement
pat.setTimestamp(1, new java.sql.Timestamp(sdf.parse(start).getTime()));
pat.setTimestamp(2, new java.sql.Timestamp(sdf.parse(end).getTime()));
rs = pat.executeQuery();
```

Comment: After fixing my spacing mistakes I was still given the same error: `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended` I have tried changing my code and using parameters like shown above and using `SimpleDateFormat("DD-MMM-YY")` However this returned the error: `Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1`

Answer (score 0):

Use PreparedStatement instead of simple statement.
You haven't provided any space after BETWEEN and before and after AND which is causing you this error.

Answer (score 0):

i think space problem between "BETWEEN" and "AND" try this

```
String query1 = "SELECT * FROM FILES WHERE USER_ID = 1 AND FILE_DATE BETWEEN " + "'" + start + "' " + "AND" + " '" + end + "';";
```

Answer (score 0):

When using JDBC, I've seen many people using a semicolon (;) at the end of the query which is absolutely wrong. Since statement and preparedStatement execute only one query at a time, it is very obvious that you won't need to end a query using semicolon explicitly.